# preventDefault and JSONP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

We have a form that should post data to an external domain. We are aware of the cross-domain limitations, therefore we want to use JSONP.

All parts are working fine, except for the part that should prevent a default form submission that reloads the page. Below is the form.

The html page:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="https://gateway.wildfx.com/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" id="wild">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email">Your email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" id="wild">
        <p class="wild_err">invalid</p>
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" id="wild_v" name="v" value="test2">
            <input type="hidden" id="wild_l" name="l" value="">
            <input type="hidden" id="wild_i" name="i" value="identifier">
            <input type="hidden" id="wild_s" name="s" value="10612">
            <input type="submit" id="wild_button" value="Check">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the Javascript. However, if the wild form is submitted, the page reloads instead of transfering the data with JSONp. In addition even the submission2 log isn't logged.

If tried to replace the .submit() with .click for the from button with correct ID but it isn't working either. What is wrong with the script?

```
function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
};
console.log('submission1');
$("#wild").submit(function(e) {     
console.log('submission2');
e.preventDefault();

    if (isValidEmailAddress(e["e"])) {
        var e = {};
        e["e"] = $("#wild_email").val();
        e["v"] = $("#wild_v").val();
        e["i"] = $("#wild_i").val();
        e["s"] = $("#wild_s").val();
        e["l"] = $("#wild_l").val();

        (function() {
                var wildAPI = "https://gateway.wildfx.com/testjsonp.php?jsoncallback=?";
                $.getJSON( wildAPI, {
                tagmode: e,
                format: "json"
            })
            .done(function( data ) {
                $(".wild_message_container").text('Success. you are in');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("#wildnotifier-container").hide();
                    $("#wildnotifier-overlay").hide();
            }, 5000);
            });
        })();
    } else {
        $(".wild_error").show();
        $("#wild_email").addClass("wild_input_error");
    }
});
```

Comment: Nothing is obviously wrong, and form submission is prevented [when I test it](http://jsfiddle.net/ev6x1f7g/). The problem, most likely, has to do with how (and when) you are loading the JavaScript into the page. You haven't shown us what script tags you are using or where they are in the page so we can't say for sure.

Comment: Javascript is loaded via an external resource, form is appended in the body.

Comment: Wait, i'll add entire script.

Answer (score 0):

1. You load jQuery
2. You load your script
3. Your script tries to add an event handler to the form
4. You add the form to your page

Step 3 fails because the form doesn't exist. Move the script so it is after the form. (Or put it in a function and call it with the DOM is ready).

Comment: Can this be the cause that it isn't working in FF but it is working in Chrome and Safari?